# PHP Simple HTML DOM, Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, object, simple-html-dom, notice

I am getting `Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object` at:

```
$var = trim($article->find('span[id$=qty]', 0)->innertext);
```

$article is a `simple_html_dom()` object.

Comment: You should post more context lines about how was $article initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `span[id$=qty]` evaluates to null; means: no node was found.

Comment: Thanks, that was the case. I just didnt see it because for some it worked and for a few the span was missing. I was trying to access a node that did not exist.