# Want to get the inner text inside the p tag 

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

The website html is like this, I want that embeded code using curl.

concept

```
<div id="postdiscriptiontext">
<p>
<embed src="http://videobb.com/e/swLN6oRlzFby" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="540" height="599"/>
</p>
</div>
I tried like this
 $html = str_get_html($links);
        echo $html->find('div.postdiscriptiontext p')->innertext . '<br>';
```

**THIS IS THE ERROR I AM GETTING**
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\anicravefinal\viewanimevideo.php on line 96

Comment: Please see the manual how this is done: [Escaping from HTML](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) - and like with the manual, you need to research a little on your own as well, I'm pretty sure your issue has been asked before, so please use the search.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Simple HTML DOM, Notice: Trying to get property of non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003991/php-simple-html-dom-notice-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object)

Comment: Also for posting a question, think about a good question title. Yours ain't one and actually "the curl concept" is a bit misleading I'd say. More important is here that you use the simple html dom library. Keep the reader in mind when posting a question. Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Content = '<div id="postdiscriptiontext">
<p>
<embed src="http://videobb.com/e/swLN6oRlzFby" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="540" height="599"/>
</p>
</div>';
preg_match_all('|<p>(.*?)</p>|',$Content,$Output);
print_r($Output);
```

Use This
If You Want to You Can try

```
$Content = file_get_contents('URL OF PAGE THAT YOU WANT TO GRAB');
```

Comment: You Can Use Different RGEX Patter, You Can Google It 
It Use For Different Matches OF PREG

Comment: There are so many like this, You specified only the particular one .But for one the soln is nice i want for all the embed videos <embed src="http://videobb.com/e/swLN6oRlzFby" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="540" height="599"/>
</p>

Comment: <div class="postlist-content"><br/>
            <div align="center">
                <?php foreach($html->find('div#postdiscriptiontext p') as $e)
            {
                
                 
            echo $e->innertext;
            ?>
         
           <?php } ?><br/>

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
    <?php
    $html = '<div id = "postdiscriptiontext">
                <p>
                    <embed src = "http://videobb.com/e/swLN6oRlzFby" type = "application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess = "always" allowfullscreen = "true" width = "540" height = "599"/>
                </p>
            </div>';

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadXML($html);
    $myHtml = $doc->getElementsByTagName("p");
    $myHtml = $myHtml->item(0)->nodeValue;
    ?>
```